# visual basic error with trying to calculate average

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I am trying to create a macro that gathers both a flat # count, and an average of existing values in a sheet. I'm getting an error at the line where i try to calculate the avgScore variable by dividing my summed up vulnScore by the counter value. I'm getting a 'runtime 6 error' at the 'avgScore = vulnScore / counter' line. It's working with a data set thats 77 lines long. I've tried converting the variables to Long (the only real suggestion I've found) but that has not worked. the 'element' variable is for an array thats about 26 in size containing string variables.

```
Dim counter As Long
Dim vulnScore As Long
Dim avgScore As Long
vulnScore = 0
counter = 0
avgScore = 0

Dim rowNum As Integer
''''''''''''''''''''
For Each element In arr
vulnScore = 0
counter = 0
avgScore = 0
'get #'s for putting into Treg
'''''''''
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
If Cells(i, 3).Value = element Then
'# of times that server is listed
counter = counter + 1
'combining vulnerability scores for that server
vulnScore = vulnScore + Cells(i, 7).Value
End If
Next i
avgScore = vulnScore / counter
'''''''''

'find Treg column/row
colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match("Findings Variance (4/15 vs Current)", ActiveWorkbook.TREG.Range("1:1"), 0)
rowNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(element, ActiveWorkbook.TREG.Range("1:1"), 0)
Cells(rowNum, colNum - 1).Value = avgScore
Cells(rowNum, colNum - 2).Value = counter
'''''''''
Next element
```

Sample: it's pulling data from this sheet which would be the activeSheet when the macro is run [image]

Sample: it's pasting the data into the two blank columns in this sheet (TREG)
[image]

Comment: can you please share excel sheet sample ?

Comment: done. added some sample screenshots

Answer (score 1):

try adding this code:

`debug.print("Vulnscore: " & vulnScore & " Counter: " & counter & " avgScore: " & vulnScore / counter)`

right before your line

```
avgScore = vulnScore / counter
```

And have a look at what get's printed

Comment: it throws the error before getting to output that debug statement. ive tried placing it where you suggested, before the 'next i' before 'end if' and before the for loop entirely. it seems like when it's getting to one of the variables its throwing the error for some reason

Comment: So before you were getting the error on: avgScore = vulnScore / counter - but now you can't even get into the: for i = ... loop without getting an error?

Comment: ive done various print checks. it iterates through the 'i' variable in the for loop correctly, the array is correctly populated. The issue is whenever i try to get it to print out vulnScore or counter within the for loop, i don't get any actual print and it goes straight to the error message. if i print those 2 variables out after the 'lastRow' for loop, i just get a return of 0 for both. It seems to be (at least partially) an issue where counter & vulnScore are not actually getting any values added to them in the loop

Answer (score 0):

You state in your comment to NautMeg's answer that both variables are 0 when it happens. That already gives you half of the answer: If `counter` is 0, you will get an divide by zero error (runtime error 11). With the exception of dividing 0 by 0, in that case VBA will not throw an divide by zero, it will throw an overflow error (runtime error 6).

You can try it by opening the immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and enter:

```
? 1/0
```

-->Runtime error 11

```
? 0/0
```

-->Runtime error 6

In any case, you have to make up your mind what you want to see in your sheet. Maybe change your code to something like

```
colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match("Findings Variance (4/15 vs Current)", ActiveWorkbook.TREG.Range("1:1"), 0)
rowNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(element, ActiveWorkbook.TREG.Range("1:1"), 0)
if counter > 0 then 
    avgScore = vulnScore / counter        
    Cells(rowNum, colNum - 1).Value = avgScore
Else
    Cells(rowNum, colNum - 1).Value = ""
End IF
Cells(rowNum, colNum - 2).Value = counter
```